# When calling execTransaction manually, it fails with GS026 - Invalid owner provided

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have signed the gnosis transaction with 2 owners and I can see this correctly in the Gnosis UI (i can even execute the transaction there). When I use the API, I get 2 confirmations with signature fields.

When trying to call the `execTransaction` method in the Gnosis Contract (using the first signer or another owner), I am concatenating the signature fields from confirmation, however, I get `GS026 - Invalid owner provided`.

I checked the gnosis contract and the failing line is

```
require(currentOwner > lastOwner && owners[currentOwner] != address(0) && currentOwner != SENTINEL_OWNERS, "GS026");
```

However, I don't know exactly what is wrong because I used the third owner to execute the transaction (it requires 2 confirmations).

Can someone give me some hints? Thanks

EDIT:

`Signature generated by Gnosis UI:`

```
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
```

`Signature generated by my script:`

```
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
```

Also pasting a screenshot from a diff tool:

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure that the confirmations are sorted?

Comment: not really. sorted in what regard?

Comment: ascending by signer address

Comment: Is this a must? Shouldn't then the results come filtered?

Comment: yes it is a must

Comment: did this and having same issues

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much I can do without seeing the transactions/signatures

Comment: adding the signatures in the question for the same gnosis transaction. first one is generated by gnosis (without executing) and the second by my script.

Comment: What you added as signatures are encoded transaction data. And they're different transactions, thats why the same signatures are not working

Comment: Yeah, wanted to say encoded transaction data, but it contains the signatures as well. It's the same transaction. Do you need the signatures?

Comment: It's not the same transaction, if it would be the same transaction then there would be no diff in encoded tx data

Comment: then I guess the issue is from somewhere else as I'm signing the same transaction with the same nonce. there is only one in the safe waiting to be executed

Comment: You can decode transaction data on etherscan and compare differing fields.